Win32: Redraw after resizing is occasionally glitchy
I'm referencing the Microsoft Win32 sample code, specifically the Direct2DCircle example. Resizing via dragging on window edges seems to mostly work properly, but there are some cases where the client area doesn't quite match up with the window size.
Resizing via maximizing/un-maximizing most clearly shows this issue. When maximizing, part of the screen is black due to the client area not fully updating to the new size. When un-maximizing, the circle does not shrink and is larger than it should be.
How can I guarantee that redrawing always matches up with resizing? I have confirmed WM_PAINT occurs after WM_SIZE. I've even tried resizing during WM_PAINT just before I render. I've also guaranteed the window size was correct just before the draw call.
The images below depict the problem.
After un-maximizing (Correct)

After un-maximizing (Incorrect)

After maximizing (Correct)

After maximizing (Incorrect)


I test the offical code, and I couldn't reproduce the issue. Could you please provide the sample to help us stable reproduction of this issue.

Can't reproduce either, have you changed something in the code, or maybe some Windows setting?

@Jeaninez-MSFT I was able to reproduce this issue without modifications and while using Visual Studio (originally, I was compiling it with Clang using the terminal). I don't think I've modified Windows in any meaningful way. However, I am using Windows 11 through an emulator (Parallels), so this might be the reason.

How many attempts did you try? I find it takes around 10-20 maximize/un-maximize actions to trigger it once.
I'm also happy to close this issue and just call it an emulator bug. If you guys aren't experiencing it, I assume users of my app won't as well. My only reservation is that I haven't been able to reproduce this with other apps such as Chromium and File Explorer, even in the emulator...

I've tried testing it a dozen times and still couldn't reproduce the issue. As far as I'm concerned, there is no issue with the code, it may be related to your test environment.
